# Multiples formularios PHP

Tags: php, html

Estoy teniendo un problema con una página web que estoy haciendo en PHP. Tengo un header con 4 slider y cada slider tiene 2 forms (8 en total y todos tienen action="contact.php"), el tema es que cuando completo uno de los formularios me llega el array $_POST vacío, como que se manda un formulario que no es el que complete. Quisiera saber como puedo hacer para recibir por POST únicamente el formulario que completo. Desde ya gracias!

```
<div class="automobile-banner-layer">
                <img src="extra-images/foto-1.jpg" alt="">
                <span class="blue-transparent"></span>
                <div class="automobile-banner-caption">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="automobile-banner-text automobile-banner-text3">
                                    <span>Tu Seguro </span>
                                    <h1>rápido y fácil</h1>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><i class="icon-check"></i>100% Digital</li>
                                        <li><i class="icon-check"></i>Contamos con las mejores compañias</li>
                                        <li><i class="icon-check"></i>Asesoramiento inmediato por WhatsApp</li>
                                    </ul>
                                    <!-- <a href="#nosotros" class="automobile-banner-btn automobile-bgcolor">Más Info</a> -->
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="automobile-banner-tabs">
                                    <!-- Nav tabs -->
                                    <ul class="nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                                        <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#banner2" aria-controls="banner2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Autos</a></li>
                                        <li role="presentation" class="radius"><a href="#banner1" aria-controls="banner1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Motos</a></li>

                                    </ul>
                                    <!-- Tab panes -->
                                    <div class="tab-content">
                                        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="banner1">
                                            <div class="automobile-banner-form">
                                                <form id="bike-1" action="contact.php" method="POST">
                                                    <ul>
                                                        <li>
                                                            <label>Nombre y Apellido:</label>
                                                            <div class="automobile-banner-submit">
                                                                <input type="text" name="name" required>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </li>
                                                        <li>
                                                            <label>Email:</label>
                                                            <div class="automobile-banner-submit">
                                                                <input type="text" name="email" required>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </li>
                                                        <li>
                                                            <label>Fecha de Nacimiento:</label>
                                                            <div class="automobile-banner-submit">
                                                                <input type="date" name="birthdate" required> 
                                                            </div>
                                                        </li>

                                                        <li>
                                                            <ul>
                                                                <li><label>Año:</label>
                                                                    <div class="automobile-banner-select">
                                                                        <select required name="year">
                                                                            <option value="2019">2019</option>
                                                                            <option value="2018">2018</option>
                                                                            <option value="2017">2017</option>
                                                                            <option value="2016">2016</option>
                                                                            <option value="2015">2015</option>
                                                                            <option value="2014">2014</option>
                                                                            <option value="2013">2013</option>
                                                                            <option value="2012">2012</option>
                                                                            <option value="2011">2011</option>
                                                                            <option value="2010">2010</option>
                                                                            <option value="2009">2009</option>
                                                                            <option value="2008">2008</option>
                                                                            <option value="2007">2007</option>
                                                                            <option value="2006">2006</option>
                                                                            <option value="2005">2005</option>
                                                                            <option value="2004">2004</option>
                                                                            <option value="2003">2003</option>
                                                                            <option value="2002">2002</option>
                                                                            <option value="2001">2001</option>
                                                                            <option value="2000">2000</option>
                                                                            <option value="1999">1999</option>
                                                                            <option value="1998">1998</option>
                                                                            <option value="1997">1997</option>
                                                                            <option value="1996">1996</option>
                                                                            <option value="1995">1995</option>
                                                                        </select>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </li>
                                                                <li>
                                                                    <label>Cobertura:</label>
                                                                    <div class="automobile-banner-select">
                                                                        <select required name="insurance">
                                                                            <option selected disabled>Seleccionar Cobertura</option>
                                                                            <option value="0">Todas</option>
                                                                            <option value="1">Básicas</option>
                                                                            <option value="2">Terceros completos</option>
                                                                            <option value="2">Todo riesgo</option>
                                                                        </select>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </li>
                                                            </ul>
                                                        </li>

                                                        <li>
                                                            <div id="vehicle">
                                                            <label>Marca:</label>
                                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                                    <div class="automobile-banner-select">
                                                                        <select name="brand" class="formmake-bike" required>
                                                                            <option value="" selected="selected">Marca</option>
                                                                        </select>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </li>
                                                        <li>
                                                            <label>Modelo:</label>
                                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                                <div class="automobile-banner-select" >
                                                                    <select name="model" class="formmodel-bike" required>
                                                                        <option value="" selected="selected">Modelo</option>
                                                                    </select>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </li>


                                                        <li>
                                                            <label>Localidad:</label>
                                                            <div class="automobile-banner-select">
                                                                <select name="location" required>
                                                                    <option selected disable>Localidad</option>
                                                                    <?php foreach($localidades as $localidad) : ?>
                                                                        <option value="<?=$localidad?>"><?= $localidad ?></option>
                                                                    <?php endforeach ?>
                                                                </select>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </li>
                                                        <li class="banner-full-form">
                                                            <label class="banner-submit"><i class="icon-search"></i><input type="submit" value="Cotizar"></label>
                                                        </li>
                                                    </ul>
                                                </form>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <!-- FORM AUTOS -->
                                        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="banner2">
                                            <div class="automobile-banner-form">
                                            <form id="car-1" action="contact.php" method="POST">
                                                    <ul>
                                                        <li>
                                                            <label>Nombre y Apellido:</label>
                                                            <div class="automobile-banner-submit">
                                                                <input type="text" name="name" required>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </li>
                                                        <li>
                                                            <label>Email:</label>
                                                            <div class="automobile-banner-submit">
                                                                <input type="text" name="email" required>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </li>
                                                        <li>
                                                            <label>Fecha de Nacimiento:</label>
                                                            <div class="automobile-banner-submit">
                                                                <input type="date" name="birthdate" required>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </li>

                                                        <li>
                                                            <ul>
                                                                <li><label>Año:</label>
                                                                    <div class="automobile-banner-select">
                                                                        <select name="year" required>
                                                                            <option value="2019">2019</option>
                                                                            <option value="2018">2018</option>
                                                                            <option value="2017">2017</option>
                                                                            <option value="2016">2016</option>
                                                                            <option value="2015">2015</option>
                                                                            <option value="2014">2014</option>
                                                                            <option value="2013">2013</option>
                                                                            <option value="2012">2012</option>
                                                                            <option value="2011">2011</option>
                                                                            <option value="2010">2010</option>
                                                                            <option value="2009">2009</option>
                                                                            <option value="2008">2008</option>
                                                                            <option value="2007">2007</option>
                                                                            <option value="2006">2006</option>
                                                                            <option value="2005">2005</option>
                                                                            <option value="2004">2004</option>
                                                                            <option value="2003">2003</option>
                                                                            <option value="2002">2002</option>
                                                                            <option value="2001">2001</option>
                                                                            <option value="2000">2000</option>
                                                                            <option value="1999">1999</option>
                                                                            <option value="1998">1998</option>
                                                                            <option value="1997">1997</option>
                                                                            <option value="1996">1996</option>
                                                                            <option value="1995">1995</option>
                                                                        </select>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </li>
                                                                <li>
                                                                    <label>Cobertura:</label>
                                                                    <div class="automobile-banner-select">
                                                                        <select required name="insurance">
                                                                            <option selected disabled>Seleccionar Cobertura</option>
                                                                            <option value="0">Todas</option>
                                                                            <option value="1">Básicas</option>
                                                                            <option value="2">Terceros completos</option>
                                                                            <option value="2">Todo riesgo</option>

                                                                        </select>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </li>
                                                            </ul>
                                                        </li>

                                                        <li>
                                                            <div id="vehicle">
                                                            <label>Marca:</label>
                                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                                    <div class="automobile-banner-select">
                                                                        <select name="brand" class="formmake-car" required>
                                                                            <option value="" selected="selected">Marca</option>
                                                                        </select>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </li>
                                                        <li>
                                                            <label>Modelo:</label>
                                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                                <div class="automobile-banner-select">
                                                                    <select name="model" class="formmodel-car" required>
                                                                        <option value="" selected="selected">Modelo</option>
                                                                    </select>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </li>

                                                        <li>
                                                            <label>Localidad:</label>
                                                            <div class="automobile-banner-select">
                                                                <select name="location"required>
                                                                    <option selected disabled>Localidad</option>
                                                                    <?php foreach($localidades as $localidad) : ?>
                                                                        <option value="<?=$localidad?>"><?= $localidad ?></option>
                                                                    <?php endforeach ?>
                                                                </select>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </li>
                                                        <li>
                                                            <div class="banner-check">
                                                                <input type="checkbox" name="gnc">
                                                                <laber>GNC</label>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </li>
                                                        <li class="banner-full-form">
                                                            <label class="banner-submit"><i class="icon-search"></i><input type="submit" value="Cotizar"></label>
                                                        </li>
                                                    </ul>
                                                </form>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Añade tu código para que podamos ayudarte mejor

Comment: Te sugiero que coloques tu cpodigo para que podamos ayudarte, por el momento te puedo comentar que tu etiqueta form debe estar por fuera de todos los sliders para que en la petición se tomen en cuanta todos los input.

Comment: Ahi publique parte del codigo, eso es un slider completo con los 2 forms

Comment: Tendrías que usar Ajax para eso. Entonces en cada formulario pondrias un botón `Enviar` y desde Javascript escuchas los clicks de esos botones, por un ID sabrás que formulario es, serializas sus datos y los mandas al servidor por medio de Ajax. También puedes optar por un solo formulario, separando los campos con `fieldset` y por un ID determinarías que set de campos fue llenado.

Comment: @A.Cedano Perfecto! Como me recibo los `fieldset` en contact.php? Muchas gracias a todos por la ayuda!

Answer (score 0):

debes tener un solo form para enviar todo lo que esté dentro de él ya que si tienes dos forms el que haga el submit es el único que se va a enviar. quedaría algo así:

```
<div class="automobile-banner-layer">
    <img src="extra-images/foto-1.jpg" alt="">
    <span class="blue-transparent"></span>
    <div class="automobile-banner-caption">
        <div class="container">
            <form id="bike-1" action="contact.php" method="POST">
                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="automobile-banner-text automobile-banner-text3">
                            <span>Tu Seguro </span>
                            <h1>rápido y fácil</h1>
                            <ul>
                                <li><i class="icon-check"></i>100% Digital</li>
                                <li><i class="icon-check"></i>Contamos con las mejores compañias</li>
                                <li><i class="icon-check"></i>Asesoramiento inmediato por WhatsApp</li>
                            </ul>
                            <!-- <a href="#nosotros" class="automobile-banner-btn automobile-bgcolor">Más Info</a> -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="automobile-banner-tabs">
                            <!-- Nav tabs -->
                            <ul class="nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                                <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#banner2" aria-controls="banner2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Autos</a></li>
                                <li role="presentation" class="radius"><a href="#banner1" aria-controls="banner1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Motos</a></li>

                            </ul>
                            <!-- Tab panes -->
                            <div class="tab-content">
                                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="banner1">
                                    <div class="automobile-banner-form">

                                            <ul>
                                                <li>
                                                    <label>Nombre y Apellido:</label>
                                                    <div class="automobile-banner-submit">
                                                        <input type="text" name="name" required>
                                                    </div>
                                                </li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <label>Email:</label>
                                                    <div class="automobile-banner-submit">
                                                        <input type="text" name="email" required>
                                                    </div>
                                                </li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <label>Fecha de Nacimiento:</label>
                                                    <div class="automobile-banner-submit">
                                                        <input type="date" name="birthdate" required> 
                                                    </div>
                                                </li>

                                                <li>
                                                    <ul>
                                                        <li><label>Año:</label>
                                                            <div class="automobile-banner-select">
                                                                <select required name="year">
                                                                    <option value="2019">2019</option>
                                                                    <option value="2018">2018</option>
                                                                    <option value="2017">2017</option>
                                                                    <option value="2016">2016</option>
                                                                    <option value="2015">2015</option>
                                                                    <option value="2014">2014</option>
                                                                    <option value="2013">2013</option>
                                                                    <option value="2012">2012</option>
                                                                    <option value="2011">2011</option>
                                                                    <option value="2010">2010</option>
                                                                    <option value="2009">2009</option>
                                                                    <option value="2008">2008</option>
                                                                    <option value="2007">2007</option>
                                                                    <option value="2006">2006</option>
                                                                    <option value="2005">2005</option>
                                                                    <option value="2004">2004</option>
                                                                    <option value="2003">2003</option>
                                                                    <option value="2002">2002</option>
                                                                    <option value="2001">2001</option>
                                                                    <option value="2000">2000</option>
                                                                    <option value="1999">1999</option>
                                                                    <option value="1998">1998</option>
                                                                    <option value="1997">1997</option>
                                                                    <option value="1996">1996</option>
                                                                    <option value="1995">1995</option>
                                                                </select>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </li>
                                                        <li>
                                                            <label>Cobertura:</label>
                                                            <div class="automobile-banner-select">
                                                                <select required name="insurance">
                                                                    <option selected disabled>Seleccionar Cobertura</option>
                                                                    <option value="0">Todas</option>
                                                                    <option value="1">Básicas</option>
                                                                    <option value="2">Terceros completos</option>
                                                                    <option value="2">Todo riesgo</option>
                                                                </select>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </li>
                                                    </ul>
                                                </li>

                                                <li>
                                                    <div id="vehicle">
                                                    <label>Marca:</label>
                                                        <div class="form-group">
                                                            <div class="automobile-banner-select">
                                                                <select name="brand" class="formmake-bike" required>
                                                                    <option value="" selected="selected">Marca</option>
                                                                </select>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <label>Modelo:</label>
                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                        <div class="automobile-banner-select" >
                                                            <select name="model" class="formmodel-bike" required>
                                                                <option value="" selected="selected">Modelo</option>
                                                            </select>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </li>


                                                <li>
                                                    <label>Localidad:</label>
                                                    <div class="automobile-banner-select">
                                                        <select name="location" required>
                                                            <option selected disable>Localidad</option>
                                                            <?php foreach($localidades as $localidad) : ?>
                                                                <option value="<?=$localidad?>"><?= $localidad ?></option>
                                                            <?php endforeach ?>
                                                        </select>
                                                    </div>
                                                </li>
                                                <li class="banner-full-form">
                                                    <label class="banner-submit"><i class="icon-search"></i><input type="submit" value="Cotizar"></label>
                                                </li>
                                            </ul>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <!-- FORM AUTOS -->
                                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="banner2">
                                    <div class="automobile-banner-form">

                                            <ul>
                                                <li>
                                                    <label>Nombre y Apellido:</label>
                                                    <div class="automobile-banner-submit">
                                                        <input type="text" name="name" required>
                                                    </div>
                                                </li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <label>Email:</label>
                                                    <div class="automobile-banner-submit">
                                                        <input type="text" name="email" required>
                                                    </div>
                                                </li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <label>Fecha de Nacimiento:</label>
                                                    <div class="automobile-banner-submit">
                                                        <input type="date" name="birthdate" required>
                                                    </div>
                                                </li>

                                                <li>
                                                    <ul>
                                                        <li><label>Año:</label>
                                                            <div class="automobile-banner-select">
                                                                <select name="year" required>
                                                                    <option value="2019">2019</option>
                                                                    <option value="2018">2018</option>
                                                                    <option value="2017">2017</option>
                                                                    <option value="2016">2016</option>
                                                                    <option value="2015">2015</option>
                                                                    <option value="2014">2014</option>
                                                                    <option value="2013">2013</option>
                                                                    <option value="2012">2012</option>
                                                                    <option value="2011">2011</option>
                                                                    <option value="2010">2010</option>
                                                                    <option value="2009">2009</option>
                                                                    <option value="2008">2008</option>
                                                                    <option value="2007">2007</option>
                                                                    <option value="2006">2006</option>
                                                                    <option value="2005">2005</option>
                                                                    <option value="2004">2004</option>
                                                                    <option value="2003">2003</option>
                                                                    <option value="2002">2002</option>
                                                                    <option value="2001">2001</option>
                                                                    <option value="2000">2000</option>
                                                                    <option value="1999">1999</option>
                                                                    <option value="1998">1998</option>
                                                                    <option value="1997">1997</option>
                                                                    <option value="1996">1996</option>
                                                                    <option value="1995">1995</option>
                                                                </select>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </li>
                                                        <li>
                                                            <label>Cobertura:</label>
                                                            <div class="automobile-banner-select">
                                                                <select required name="insurance">
                                                                    <option selected disabled>Seleccionar Cobertura</option>
                                                                    <option value="0">Todas</option>
                                                                    <option value="1">Básicas</option>
                                                                    <option value="2">Terceros completos</option>
                                                                    <option value="2">Todo riesgo</option>

                                                                </select>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </li>
                                                    </ul>
                                                </li>

                                                <li>
                                                    <div id="vehicle">
                                                    <label>Marca:</label>
                                                        <div class="form-group">
                                                            <div class="automobile-banner-select">
                                                                <select name="brand" class="formmake-car" required>
                                                                    <option value="" selected="selected">Marca</option>
                                                                </select>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <label>Modelo:</label>
                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                        <div class="automobile-banner-select">
                                                            <select name="model" class="formmodel-car" required>
                                                                <option value="" selected="selected">Modelo</option>
                                                            </select>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </li>

                                                <li>
                                                    <label>Localidad:</label>
                                                    <div class="automobile-banner-select">
                                                        <select name="location"required>
                                                            <option selected disabled>Localidad</option>
                                                            <?php foreach($localidades as $localidad) : ?>
                                                                <option value="<?=$localidad?>"><?= $localidad ?></option>
                                                            <?php endforeach ?>
                                                        </select>
                                                    </div>
                                                </li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <div class="banner-check">
                                                        <input type="checkbox" name="gnc">
                                                        <laber>GNC</label>
                                                    </div>
                                                </li>
                                                <li class="banner-full-form">
                                                    <label class="banner-submit"><i class="icon-search"></i><input type="submit" value="Cotizar"></label>
                                                </li>
                                            </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```